# Transactions for patches in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

RavenDb does not support transactions for Patches. But in a pretty much any high-load project Patch is the only way to go (due to concurrency problems). Inevitably you have situations when you need to execute a sequence of patches:

AddLikeToCommentLikes(...);
AddLikeToUserLikes(...) //needed to show a user which comment he liked

Based on my experience typically there is a primary change and a secondary (which could be recovered if lost). But sometimes there are several equally important changes.

So what is the best practice in this case to make either none of the patches happen or all of them? Is there any way to emulate transaction for several patches?

The only idea I have in this regards is to merge changes into one script patch. So we have a script that adds a comment like, then in the same script we get UserLikes document with LoadDocument and modify it. But I doubt RavenDb guarantees UserLikes is not modified within this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB does support transactions for patches, as long as you are patching by id.
If you are patching by query, the operation is handled as a transaction for each individual document, but not globally.

Calling LoadDocument in a patch will result in *all* documents modified by a patch sharing the same transaction, so either all the patch changes are saved, or it didn't happen in an atomic fashion